# Change the button's color after form is filed out

Tags: javascript, forms

Trying to add to functions to this form:

1. validate email (seems to work only when any other JS is commented out)
2. change color of button when form is filled

Here's my code https://github.com/SallyRagab/WPMU-DEV

```
// validate email address
var email = document.getElementById('email');

function validateEmail() {
  var emailValue = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var pattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
  if (emailValue.match(pattern)) {
    email.classList.remove("is-invalid");
  } else {
    email.classList.add("is-invalid");
  }
}

email.addEventListener('keydown', validateEmail);


// // validate password
var password = document.getElementById('password');

function validatePassword() {
  var passwordValue = document.getElementById('password').value;
  if (passwordValue.length >= 7) {
    password.classList.remove("is-invalid");
  } else {
    password.classList.add("is-invalid");
  }
}

password.addEventListener('keydown', validatePassword);


// Change color of button when form is filled
var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('input');

function changeColor(){
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
      var inputValue = inputFields[i].value;
      list.push(inputValue);
  }
  if (!(list.includes('')) && !(email.classList.contains("is-invalid")) &&  !(password.classList.contains("is-invalid"))) {
    button.classList.add('active-btn');
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
      inputFields[i].addEventListener('input', changeColor);}
```

Comment: `if (list not includes(''))` is not a valid statement, there is a closing bracket missing at `email.addEventListener('keydown', validation;`, what is `input` in `input.addEventListener('input', changeColor);`?

Answer (score 0):

there's a syntax error.

```
email.addEventListener('keydown', validation; //missing closing parenthesis
```

Also when you say:

```
input.addEventListener('input', changeColor);
```

I could not find `input` variable. May you wanted to loop over `forms` variable and add event listeners to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I have solved the issue and all functions are working as expected.

```
// validate email address
var email = document.getElementById('email');

function validateEmail() {
  var emailValue = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var pattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
  if (emailValue.match(pattern)) {
    email.classList.remove("is-invalid");
  } else {
    email.classList.add("is-invalid");
  }
}

email.addEventListener('keydown', validateEmail);


// // validate password
var password = document.getElementById('password');

function validatePassword() {
  var passwordValue = document.getElementById('password').value;
  if (passwordValue.length >= 7) {
    password.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    password.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    password.classList.add("is-invalid");
    password.classList.remove("valid");
  }
}

password.addEventListener('keydown', validatePassword);


// Change color of button when form is filled
var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('input');

function changeColor(){
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
      var inputValue = inputFields[i].value;
      list.push(inputValue);
  }
  if (!(list.includes('')) && !(email.classList.contains("is-invalid")) &&  !(password.classList.contains("is-invalid"))) {
    button.classList.add('active-btn');
  } else {
    button.classList.remove('active-btn');
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
      inputFields[i].addEventListener('input', changeColor);}
```